# STL Map where is _Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance implemented?

Tags: c++, dictionary, red-black-tree

I was looking through how the STL `std::map` is implemented. I knew that it is implemented using Red Black Trees. So, I just was curious to know how Red Black Trees are implemented in STL for reasons of knowing how efficient the implementation is.

`std::map` includes `stl_tree.h`. This is where the Red Black Tree is implemented.

All the functions (where insert takes place) abstract the insertion and calls `_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance` function. But I could not find the implementation of this.

Any ideas where it is implemented?

Comment: If by STL you mean the C++ standard library (as suggested by the `std` namespace), then it is purely implementation dependent. So you should clarify which standard library implementation you mean. If you really mean the STL, then there is no `std::map` in it (just `map`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's fully implementation-specific, however, I think you mean `libstdc++`, so, since realization is open-source - you can search for this function in source files. In `gcc-4.8` this function is in file `libstdc++-v3/src/c++98/tree.cc`.
For example you can search it here: [github gcc sources](https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/src/c++98/tree.cc)

Comment: Thanks. I was looking through the gcc includes available in the installation directory and could not find this.

Comment: Just a nitpicky note: formally, it's not implementation defined, since the language definition says that "implementation-defined" means that a conforming implementation must document what it does. It is, however, implementation specific.